# Problems with the internet

Tags: networking, internet

I switched over to ubuntu 14.04.3 the other day after my windows got corrupted. now im just lost. the laptop connects to the internet just fine at my house, however, i fixed up the laptop for a friend to use and the internet just wont work at his house. it says it's connected to his wifi, but nothing will load. i tried pinging google.com and got 0 responses. we tried to play a game while we had it connected to my wifi, but the ping was rediculously high, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the laptop's ip set as a static ip or a dynamic ip?

Comment: How would i find that with ubuntu? i know that i could find it with "ipconfig" in windows, but that doesn't seem to work with ubuntu.

Comment: Unix and Linux use `ifconfig` for future reference, but it's usually easier to go into System Settings>>Network.

Comment: when i checked, the ip was the same both times. so it looks like it's static

Answer (score 0):

It could be a DNS server issue. Try pinging an IP instead of a domain name:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

If that doesn't give you any issues, you should switch to a public DNS service like OpenDNS or Google Public DNS.

Comment: i tried this and it didnt help, though i could ping 8.8.8.8 and not a web address.

Comment: That's indicative of a DNS issue. Are you sure that you configured OpenDNS/Google DNS correctly? Personally, I use Google DNS. If you need more information on how to set it up, use the following guide: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en